# qlikview syntax - uniq key

Tags: excel, uniq, qlikview

I've an excel file with 4 fields :a,b,c,key.
I need to check in QV script that for each row a,b,c there is only on key.
The rows that have diffrent keys should be the result.
for example this is an uncorrect situation that I need to catch :

key |   c      |    b      |    a

111 |   test3  |    test2  |    test1

222 |   test3  |    test2  |    test1

anyone has an idea how can it be done in qlikview?

thanks,
Lena.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I suggest treating columns `c + b + a` as a composite key and counting the number of unique values in the field `key` for each composite key. Here is one way to do that (`QlikView` script):

```
DATA:
LOAD key, c, b, a
FROM some_file.xls;

LEFT JOIN(DATA)
LOAD c, b, a, COUNT(DISTINCT key) AS key_count
RESIDENT DATA
GROUP BY c, b, a;
```

Your data model now has a 5th column named `key_count`. You can now use `key_count` in a chart or list box, or another LOAD statement with a WHERE clause, to filter the rows that have 2 or more values in the field `key`. To expand on your sample data:

```
key | c | b | a | key_count
111 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2
222 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2
333 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1
444 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1
```

In a list box or LOAD statement, you can now easily find the rows where `key_count > 1`. I hope this helps!